# Does a page with a phone number in the title rank less well in Google?

Tags: seo, google-search, title

I am creating a website in asp.net and I am making the phone number visible in the title bar. Will this method have an effect on SEO?  Will Google lower my rank?  If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

The title of your page is the place where keywords that you use have the most weight to Google.   Including the phone number in the title is NOT a good SEO practice.

- The phone number is easy to rank for (since it is unique to you).   When somebody searches for your phone number Google will show your site even if the page only contains it in the body.
- Putting the phone number in the title leaves less room for other important words, especially your business name
- The title of the page is shown to users in the search results.   It is important to have descriptive text about your website there so that users know something about the website.  Otherwise they won't click on it.   A phone number is not very descriptive
- The title of your page often gets used as the anchor text for inbound links.   Keywords are very important in inbound links as well and the phone number is not a great keyword.

The things that you probably do want to include in the title of a business home page are:

- The name of the business (eg "Johnny Spotless")
- The type of the business (eg "dry cleaners")
- And the city or town of the business (eg, "Hollywood, CA")

You also don't say whether your phone number is the *only* thing you were planning to put in the title.  If your users are really expecting to see it there, you *could* include it, but I would but it second or third, not the very first thing.   For SEO, the beginning of the title has more weight than the end.

Most website have many pages on them.   Your titles should be unique on each and every page.  You don't say if you are considering the phone number as the title for *every* page.  That would certainly NOT be appropriate.   Internal pages should describe their content with the title.   It is also a good idea to end them with the business name.  Such a page might be "Hours of operation - Johnny Spotless"